# The referenced component 'Microsoft.Owin', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook' could not be found?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I checked out an Asp.Net project created a few years ago using Visual Studio 2017. However, the project cannot be compiled now with the error of Owin components.

The three Owin components under references node in Solution Explorer have yellow triangles with exclamation points. However, the NuGet package manager shows these components are installed?

**Update:**
I resolved the problem by downgrading Microsoft.Owin from 3.1.0 to 2.1.0 and it compiles now.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: So I have verified that they're still there in 3.1.0; however, in my case, I had to remove them from the project and re-add them using the NuGet Package Manager. Each one had a "click to accept" license, but after I re-added them, it worked. I am left wondering if it was the license issue, or that they possibly weren't added via the NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downgrading **Microsoft.Owin**. you can do the below step.
Add the assembly redirect in your application's configuration file

```html
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">      
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```